# ts Cannot find name 'model' in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 4 and i am getting `[ts] Cannot find name 'model'` error in 
 my angular 4 project. kindly help to me where is my mistake. 
 Thanks in advance.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer }    from './customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-profile',
  templateUrl: './customer-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-profile.component.css']
})
export class CustomerProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
   model = new Customer(1,'vikram','R',25);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variable you are using in typescript.

If `model` is a class variable do:

```
export class CustomerProfileComponent implements OnInit {

model:Customer;//declare here
  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.model = new Customer(1,'vikram','R',25);//use this to access
  }

}
```

Or if it is a local variable,

```
 ngOnInit() {
  let model:Customer = new Customer(1,'vikram','R',25);//use let to access
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer }    from './customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-profile',
  templateUrl: './customer-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-profile.component.css']
})
export class CustomerProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
   }
  model:Customer;
  ngOnInit() {
   this.model = new Customer(1,'vikram','R',25);
  }

}
```

You need to declare the variable before using it.